# Setting up Redux Provider for Jest Testing

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to setup a redux provider for Jest testing with my react app.
From what I understand I need something like this

```
import {ReactNode} from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {store} from "../redux/reducer/store";

type PropsWithOptionalChildren<P = unknown> = P & { children?: ReactNode };
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store>    
interface ReduxProviderProps extends PropsWithChildren {
    store: RootState,
}

const ReduxProvider = ({children, store}: ReduxProviderProps) => <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>

export default ReduxProvider
```

Which I then use like this

```
test("...", () => {
  const store = configureStore();
  const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    <ReduxProvider reduxStore={store}>{children}</ReduxProvider>
  );
  ...
});
```

However, the compiler complains about the following line

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store>
```

> type [...] does not satisfy the constraint  (...args: any) => any 
> type [...] provides no match for the signature  (...args: any): any

This is the `store` variable

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: false
        }).concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});
```

And additional information

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    a: aReducer,
    b: bReducer,
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
})

const config = getPersistConfig({
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    blacklist: ['a'],
    rootReducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer)
```

How to resolve the compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Change RootState type to as below and see if it resolves

`type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>`

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried

Comment: I forgot to update answer after copy paste and it's just mistake.